# Varying style for chapter-references

Tags: sectioning, numbering, roman-numerals

I would like to refer to a chapter (roman numbering) partly with arabic numerals (e.g. as part of equation numbers) and partly with roman numerals (e.g. when refering directly to the chapter) ...

I've tried sth like:

```
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{\def\thechapter{\roman{chapter}}\ref{#1}}
```

(this changed the counter format globally)

or

```
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral \ref{#1}}}
```

(in may case: compiled without warning but no effect..)

but this didn't work out ... any ideas?

Comment: @firstshot: What is the problem with your solution? Please help use helping you.

Comment: Don't redefine `\thechapter` if what you really want to do is change how `\theequation` looks: this will lead to other changes you don't want. Since it's `\theequation` you want to look differently, redefine _that_.

Answer (score 5):

The command

```
\def\thechapter{\roman{chapter}}
```

switches the default chapter numbering to roman numerals. You should do this once, at the start.
To use arabic numbers in the equation numbers, define these, too:

```
\def\theequation{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
```

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann and Seamus: Thanks a lot - actually I primarly wanted to use the arabic style and only occasionally the roman style - hence I was thinking the wrong way :) **Your solution works perfectly fine!** Ok, u probably know it - but maybe not everyone else out there ... so I used: 1. \def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} 2. \def\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}} 3. \def\thesubsection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}} 4. \def\theequation{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}} 5. \def\thetheorem{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}} Thanks for the help! cheers!

Comment: @firstshot: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please mark this answer as the solution by clicking the tick-mark on the left side. This marks the question as solved automatically. Please do not edit the title for this. Also posts in this section are for solutions only, so I converted your post, which is mostly a thank-you post, to a comment. You are very welcome to post your final solutions as own answers if required. However, in this simple case I would say the comment is sufficient.